# Remove part of a string until a character is found R

Tags: r, string, split, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex problem or somewhat regex related problem...

I have strings that look like this:

```
"..........))))..)))))))"
"....))))))))...)).))))..))"
"......))))...)))...)))))"
```

I want to remove the initial dot sequence, so that I only get the string starting by the first occurence of ")" symbol. Say, the output would be somthing like:

```
"))))..)))))))"
"))))))))...)).))))..))"
"))))...)))...)))))"
```

I assume it would be somewhat similar to a lookahead regex but cannot figure out the correct one...

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We match for 0 or more dots (`\\.*`) from the start (`^`) of the string and replace it with blank

```
sub("^\\.*", "", v1)
#[1] "))))..)))))))"          "))))))))...)).))))..))" "))))...)))...)))))"
```

If it needs to start from `)`, then as above match 0 or more dots till the first `)` and replace with the `)`

```
sub("^\\.*\\)", ")", v1)
#[1] "))))..)))))))"          "))))))))...)).))))..))" "))))...)))...)))))"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("..........))))..)))))))", "....))))))))...)).))))..))", "......))))...)))...)))))")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove dots from the beginning of the line (marked in the regex by `^`) until you reach a non-dot character:

```
a <- "..........))))..)))))))"
b <- "....))))))))...)).))))..))"
c <- "......))))...)))...)))))"

sub("^\\.*", "", a) # "))))..)))))))"
sub("^\\.*", "", b) # "))))))))...)).))))..))"
sub("^\\.*", "", c) # "))))...)))...)))))"
```

Answer (score 1):

The way your question is worded, the goal isn't to remove just . from the beginning, but any symbol until the first ) is encountered. So this answer is a more general solution.

```
stringr::str_extract("..........))))..)))))))","\\).*$")
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick with base R, you could use sub/gsub like this:

```
gsub("[^\\)]*(\\).*$)","\\1","..........))))..)))))))")
sub("[^\\)]*","","..........))))..)))))))")
```